# SWT Tree ScrollBar

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar

I have a Tree in SWT that I am trying to add a vertical scroll-bar to. I have tried `SWT.V_SCROLL` and even adding it to a Tree Viewer and adding a scroll-bar to that, but every time it just gives me the complete tree without any scroll-bars. Any idea how to add the scrollbars?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Scrollbars only appear if you use a scrolledComposite. You have place the content that you want scrolled inside of a scrolledComposite it will take care of adding the scrollbars for you when the content inside the scrolledComposite is larger than the viewable area of the scrolledComposite.

Here is the doc for scrolledComposite, the examples are quite helpful.

[ScrolledComposite JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FScrolledComposite.html)

Comment: -1 Scrollbars appear even on just the Table. It all depends on the size of the table. If you restrict its size (preferably with a Layout) below what's necessary to show all the elements, it will show scrollbars. [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ScrollaSWTtablesetthetopindex.htm).

Comment: The big disadvantage of using a `ScrolledComposite` in combination with a `Table` is, that the headers scroll as well, which they wouldn't without it.

Comment: The original question was not asking about how to use scrollbars with a tree, not a table.
If you don't want the scroll bars to appear when you don't need them you can use setAlwaysShowScrollBars and set the value to false.

Comment: @Psisous Yeah, realized that when I couldn't edit the comment anymore, however there is only a minor difference. Both my arguments still apply.